# add delay so that the user can see the textview changing

Tags: java, android, xml, delay, sleep

i have 1 textview and using a button to change the text.
I am setting 2 strings to the same textview, so i want a delay before the text changes from 1st string to the 2nd.

```
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

              {
         public void onClick(View v1) 
            {

          final DBUserAdapter dbUser = new DBUserAdapter(agenmin.this);
        dbUser.open();

        Cursor mCursor1=dbUser.Getmess(easyPuzzle);
        String mess=mCursor1.getString(0);
          textView1.setText(mess);
        //want some delay here but how??
        //postDelayed();
            //SystemClock.sleep(5000);

        String ab=mCursor1.getString(1);
        textView3.setText(ab);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){        
        textView3.setText(ab);
    }
}, delayTImeinMilis);
```

Comment: working but i have to open(); the database again get the cursor get many other values again in public void run().

Comment: sorry can't get you.. can you please describe a bit more @pantera

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread and sleep it,or you can use simply an `AsyncTask` and delay in it's `doInBackground()` and change text in it's `onPostExecute()`.